# What is the probability that in a company of $500$ people, only two persons will have birthdays on New Year’s Day?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations, birthday

What is the probability that in a company of 500 people, only two persons will have birthdays on New Year’s Day?
I feel the answer is

=$\frac{1}{365}\cdot\frac{1}{365}\cdot\frac{364}{365}\cdot\frac{364}{365}\cdots\frac{364}{365}$
=$$\frac{1}{365^{2}}.\frac{364^{498}}{365^{498}}$$

And Not=
$$\binom{500}2\cdot\frac{1}{365^{2}}\cdot\frac{364^{498}}{365^{498}}$$

Basically in the second answer they have first selected 2 out of 500 people...which I am not sure is necessary here or not...
Coz what I gave a thought when I saw the problem ..that only 2 people means ..there are some predetermined or fixed 2 people and so I am not supposed to select first 2 out of 500 before I go in solving this question...
(Plz tell was my thought actually making any sense..??)

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem

Comment: If it is indeed "what is the probability that employee 1 and employee 2 are the only two people with birthdays on New Years Day" your first answer is correct. However, in standard math/word problem parlance, the problem means "exactly two people, but we don't specify which two." If this is for school, I'd suggest giving both answers if you aren't sure ("if the problem mean to to specify two particular people than.... otherwise if it meant any two people..."). If you are just learning for your own sake, as long as you understand how both situations work, I think you are fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem related to the [Binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution). Maybe it helps considering the smaller case of having two out of four people with a birthday on New Year's day. Let's define the events $A$, $B$, $C$ and $D$ as the events in which the first, second, third and fourth person has their birthday on $1$ January. Then, the following cases are all valid:

$$A, B, C^\mathsf{c}, D^\mathsf{c}$$
$$A, B^\mathsf{c}, C, D^\mathsf{c}$$
$$A, B^\mathsf{c}, C^\mathsf{c}, D$$
$$A^\mathsf{c}, B, C, D^\mathsf{c}$$
$$A^\mathsf{c}, B, C^\mathsf{c}, D$$
$$A^\mathsf{c}, B^\mathsf{c}, C, D$$

The number of valid cases equals ${4 \choose 2} = 6$, i.e., the number of ways in which we can select two people out of four. The probability of each of these cases to appear, equals:

$$\frac{1}{365}\frac{1}{365}\frac{364}{365}\frac{364}{365} = \frac{364^2}{365^4}$$

Therefore, the probability of having exactly two out of four people whose birthday is on a specific day, equals:

$${4 \choose 2} \frac{364^2}{365^4} \approx 0.0000448$$

In general, if an event occurs with probability $p$, the probability of having $k$ out of $n$ occurrences equals:

$${n \choose k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k}$$

Comment: Thanks !! Your explanation made my concept more clear...and good thought of binomial Distribution though..I had solved many binomial distribution problem...still wasn't able to recognize this as a Binomial based one...!! Thanks for the approach...again!!

Comment: Now consider a scenario where I have been told that there are specific 2 people Say Alice and Bob have birthdays on same day as of new year's day..then if it was asked to find the probabilty of same above question...? ( I think in that case nothing would make sense coz we already know who two are going to get the same birth date so that would be simply a sure event with probabilty as 1..and the point why I was confused to whether or not take 500C2 or not was absolutely meaning less...isn't it...??)

Answer (score 1):

$\binom{500}{2}$ is indeed required. You need to know (and be able to count) which 2 people are born on New year's day.

Comment: What if they had directly given that "there are some 2 particular people..." Then in that case I won't take $500C2$ (am I right??)

Comment: @PiyushSawarkar that is correct.